# Benford's Law Plotting in Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I've been stumped with a task I've been assigned that requires me to output a data set read from a CSV file...

...with the Benford's Law result in a bar graph like this:

Benford Bar Graph example

[image]

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import csv
import locale

with open("immigrants.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
    immidata = csv.reader(csvfile)
    X_labels = []
    Y = []
    for row in immidata:
        X_labels.append(row[0])
        Y.append(locale.atoi(row[1]))

numbers = [float(n) for n in range(1, 10)]
benford = [math.log10(1 + 1 / d) for d in numbers]
plt.plot(numbers, benford, 'ro', label = "Benford's Law")
plt.bar(numbers, range(1, 11), align = 'left', normed = True, 
    rwidth = 0.7, label = "Actual data")
plt.bar(benford, range(1, 11), align = 'left', normed = True, 
    rwidth = 0.7, label = "Predicted data")
plt.title("Immigrants in countries")
plt.xlabel("Digit")
plt.ylabel("Probability")
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.xticks(numbers)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And here's some of the info in the CSV file which shows the number of immigrants in each country (Country, Number of immigrants, Percentage of total number of immigrants in the world, and Immigrants as percentage of national population, respectively):

```
United States,"45,785,090",19.8,14.3
Russia,"11,048,064",4.8,7.7
Germany,"9,845,244",4.3,11.9
Saudi Arabia,"9,060,433",3.9,31.4
United Arab Emirates,"7,826,981",3.4,83.7
United Kingdom,"7,824,131",3.4,12.4
```

My output right now:

```
line 19, in <module>
  Y.append(locale.atoi(row[1]))
line 321, in atoi
  return int(delocalize(string))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Number of
immigrants'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm still relatively new to this so any advice that will help me get an output is extremely appreciated!

Thank you!

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkUpR.png)

Output that needs to look like the sample.

Comment: There is more than one comma in the line so the `split(",")` returns more than 2 items. You may want to look into the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) module which provides appropriate handling of csv files.

Comment: I've never used the csv module before... how would I use it in my situation?

Comment: Try reading the documentation I've linked to - in particular look at `csv.reader`. If you get stuck, then come back to SO with the problem. You will get more help if you show you've tried.

Comment: I have. Trying it myself has led me to printing the whole file but with commas after every word.

Comment: is this question about plotting or reading data or about Benford's Law?

Comment: This is about reading data and making bar graph displaying the actual data and the theorized Benford data in one bar graph. My result is supposed to be the graph you see in the post.

Comment: Why have you defined the `delimiter` of your csv file as being a `' '` when clearly it is comma separated.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry! It's been revised! Thank you for pointing that out. I wasn't too sure on what delimiter actually did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using pandas:

This plot the Benford law against the number of immigrants

EDIT: 
Your file probably has a header row  indicated by the string 'Number of Immigration' in the num_immigrants column.  Remove the `header=None` option in the line that reads the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set the width of the bars, you're gonna have to massage this
width = 0.35

immi = pd.read_csv('immigrants.csv')

# name columns
immi.columns = ['country', 'num_immigrants', 'perc_world', 'perc_nat_pop']

# convert num_immigrants to float
immi.num_immigrants=  immi.num_immigrants.str.replace(',', '').apply(float)
total = immi.num_immigrants.sum()

# scale the immigration to between 0 and 1
immi['immi_scaled'] = immi['num_immigrants'].apply(lambda x: x/total)

indx = np.arange(1, len(immi) + 1)
benford = [np.log10(1 + (1.0 / d)) for d in indx]

plt.bar(indx, benford, width, color='r', label="Benford's Law")
plt.bar(np.arange(1, immi.shape[0]+1)+ width, 
                immi.immi_scaled, width, color='b', label="Predicted data")
# center the xtick labels
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(indx + width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels((indx))

# limit the  number of bars if you have more data
plt.xlim(1, 9)
plt.title("Immigrants in countries")
plt.ylabel("Probability")
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MarcleSparkle/PycharmProjects/01-bendfords_law/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    immi.num_immigrants=immi.num_immigrants.str.replace(',', '').apply(float)
  File "/Users/MarcleSparkle/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2220, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 1088, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:62658)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Number of immigrants'`

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'total' is not defined`

Comment: sorry about the buggy code @Marc I just made some changes and ran the code, it works now.

Comment: So close! Now it's `ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 228 or scalar`

Comment: you're almost there! I built this example using the sample you provided in the question. I can't tell where that error is coming from exactly. what the full stacktrace?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):                                                               line 25, in <module>
    plt.bar(indx, benford, width, color='r')
 line 2650, in bar
    **kwargs)
line 1819, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
line 2038, in bar
    "must be length %d or scalar" % nbars)
ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 228 or scalar`

Comment: ok, I see the issue, `numbers` should be used to define `benford`. the most recent code should run w/o issues! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! My last gripe is just the formatting. My graph looks like [this](http://i66.tinypic.com/5jw87t.png). How can I change the code to make it look like the sample chart?

Comment: I dont see the image on that site, can you post it here?

Comment: Okay a link to the image is now in my post! :) @putonspectacles the bars need to be side by side and the x-axis ticks need to be from 1 through 9 centralized.

Comment: that actually is benford law plotted againt _all_ your data. If you want to limit what is shown in the chart you can use `xlim(1, 9)`.

Comment: That solved that! I just need to center both bars on the ticks and I'm done! I can't seem to adjust it just right yet.. btw I appreciate all the help!

Comment: no worries,  glad I can help! see the updated code for how to center the xticklabels.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the data:

```
import locale

with open("immigrants.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
    immidata = csv.reader(csvfile)  # defaults are fine!
    X_labels = []
    Y = []
    for row in immidata:
        X_labels.append(row[0])
        Y.append(locale.atoi(row[1]))
```

Gives you your `X_labels` and `Y` (converted to an int).
Note: no need to `close()` the `with` block automatically does that.

Good luck on the rest of it. BTW: `digits` is undefined in the code you shared - you should make every attempt to make it [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks! For some reason though it's tell me that "reader is not defined" as an error.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. I appreciate the help! For some strange reason, however, I'm getting a strange error that I posted in the OP.

Comment: Looks like you have a header row that you don't show in your sample data, take a look at `csv.dictreader`.

Comment: Ah, I see. The strange thing that changing     'csv.reader' into 'csv.DictReader' gave me 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MarcleSparkle/PycharmProjects/01-bendfords_law/benford.py", line 17, in <module>
    X_labels.append(row[0])
KeyError: 0'

Comment: With `DictReader` you use column names not indexes.